# How do I list all the records that satisfy a given condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a database with timestamp and counter reading from a machine for every minute.
I want to write a query to display timestamp for all the rows when the counter reading was zero.

| datetime | m00 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-03 10:00 | 10 |
| 2021-11-03 10:01 | 9 |
| 2021-11-03 10:02 | 0 |
| 2021-11-03 10:03 | 8 |
| 2021-11-03 10:04 | 10 |
| 2021-11-03 10:05 | 0 |
| 2021-11-03 10:06 | 10 |
| 2021-11-03 10:07 | 10 |

Expected result-1 (all zero count rows)

| datetime | m00 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-03 10:02 | 0 |
| 2021-11-03 10:05 | 0 |

Expected result-2 (all non-zero count rows)

| datetime | m00 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-03 10:00 | 10 |
| 2021-11-03 10:01 | 9 |
| 2021-11-03 10:03 | 8 |
| 2021-11-03 10:04 | 10 |
| 2021-11-03 10:06 | 10 |
| 2021-11-03 10:07 | 10 |

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want but, check below answer and let me know if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
                          `datetime` timestamp,
                          `m00` int(11)  
                        );

INSERT INTO `my_table`  
VALUES
      ('2021-11-03 10:00',10),
      ('2021-11-03 10:01',9),
      ('2021-11-03 10:02',0),
      ('2021-11-03 10:03',8),
      ('2021-11-03 10:04',10),
      ('2021-11-03 10:05',0),
      ('2021-11-03 10:06',10),
      ('2021-11-03 10:07',10);

SELECT `datetime`, 
       `m00` as all_zero_count_rows
FROM my_table
WHERE `m00`=0;


SELECT `datetime`, 
       `m00` as all_non_zero_count_rows
FROM my_table
WHERE `m00` !=0;
```

Or if you want in one query:

```
SELECT `datetime`,
        case when `m00`=0 then  m00 else ' ' end as all_zero_count_rows,
        case when `m00` !=0 then  m00 else ' ' end as all_non_zero_count_rows
FROM my_table;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qff694udysNgqbyJyFcDzn/1

**

> `datetime` is a reserved word in `MySQL` it should be inside backticks
> or rename the column.

**

Comment: Excellent, SELECT `datetime`,
        case when `m00`=0 then  m00 else ' ' end as all_zero_count_rows,
        case when `m00` !=0 then  m00 else ' ' end as all_non_zero_count_rows
FROM my_table;